# No results found for second level category

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, tax-query

I am trying to retrieve posts from a category. I have 2 level and 3 level category hierarchy. I am using tax query in pre get posts filter to alter the query.

The query works fine for the first level and third level category but shows no result for second level category. The query when examined has 0 = 1 added in the where clause for queries which yield no result.

For 2 level category the query works fine both for parent and child category.

I have woocommerce setup with Wordpress.

Below is the filter added:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'alter_category_search_query');

function alter_category_search_query($query) {
  if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) {
    $args = array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $_GET['cat'],
        'include_children' => false
      )
    );
    $query->set('tax_query', $args);

    //we remove the actions hooked on the '__after_loop' (post navigation)
    remove_all_actions('__after_loop');
  }
}
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON
(wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( 
wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (17) 
AND 
0 = 1
) AND ( 
( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN 
('visible','search') )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title 
ASC
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to contain the code? It's not possible to answer the question without it

Comment: @TomJNowell updated my question with code. Please help.

Comment: Do you actually have any products associated with those categories?

Comment: @MarkKaplun Yes i do

Comment: what is the generated sql? but it sounds like something local to your settings/plugins

Comment: @MarkKaplun updated question with generated SQL

Comment: I don't see any post loops, just a `pre_get_posts` filter, when you say 3rd level, can you be more specific? 3rd level into nested loops? Or are you talking about a category page for a category that's 3 levels down?

Comment: @TomJNowell 3rd level meant Parent Cat -> Child Cat -> Child Category. I am trying to get products on a search page when user selects a particular category.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of the function generating the SQL for the term part of queries https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/get_sql_for_clause/, it seems like a `0 = 1` is a symptom of bad parameters given in the query, so while you think you are passing the right parameters, apparently you don't.

Only way to move forward is probably to debug what exactly happens in that function to understand what fails.

Side note: It is always a bad idea to use unsanitized url parameters, additionally the use of `cat` as parameter seems like a bad idea unless you truly mean it to collide with the general post categories.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue. The issue was incorrect syntax for the $args array. I had to wrap 'terms' value around an array even if its a single value.
so it needs to be

```
$args = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => array($_GET['cat']),
    'include_children' => false
  )
);
```